# How could I fix this errror message at VcXsrv ? Trying to use WSL 2 using graphical apps under VcXsrv Xserver

Tags: windows-10, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, x-server

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS at Windows 10 Professional build 19041.329 and would like to run graphical apps at X server. Did a install of Docker Desktop and did a test and it's working fine.

But with focus on the graphical apps I installed:
[VcXsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/)

VT-x is enabled at BIOS, WSL 2 is active under Windows 10 Pro.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wsl -l -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-20.04           Running         2
  docker-desktop-data    Stopped         2
  docker-desktop         Stopped         2
```

I disabled at Windows 10 the domain, public and private **Firewall** zones and at Ubuntu 20.04 LTS I did:

```
$ sudo ufw disable
```

I followed this tutorial to install Docker:
[Docker Install at WSL2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-20-04)

I have used the same IP address from WSL interface (Windows 10):

```
$sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
$sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

Did the steps:

```
$nano .bashrc

export DISPLAY=SAMEIP_of_WSL_IFACE:0 -> put at the EOF.

source ~/.bashrc
```

When I did run one time and launched Xserver for Windows with success (show the black screen).

But now I facing this message at VcxSvr when I click Xlaunch not open and show this:
[image]

Tried with regular user and root like image bellow:
[image]

Have no clue about...Tried to put in the WSL a static IP, used Privazer (cleanup windows) and nothing...

Comment: I have not had luck with the desktop environment.  Remoting your DISPLAY variable isn't for remoting the window manager anyways.  VcXSrv IS your window manager.  Start simple, uninstall xfce4, apt-get install xterm.  Change all of the IPs to loopback.  Fix your DISPLAY export to 127.0.0.1:0.0 <- note the second ".0".  Make THAT work.  You should be able to launch xterm & and get an xterm in windows.  Expand from there (a working checkpoint).

Comment: Thanks @SeñorCMasMas i think it was going well now... Please vote for accept my reply... Can't do myself...

Comment: I gave you a point but I can't accept your answer either. :^P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following command:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2}'
```

And I have edited **.bashrc** and give a ***source .bashrc***.

So worked fine!

[image]